# Flutter how to run a timer in background and starts a screen when the timer is completed?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to create a basic alarm application which will show a screen to user from which he can snooze or complete the task.

I have found this Package [android_alarm_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager) but this only works with Android,

I have also found that Isolates are paused in IOs after a short period of time in my case it will be a problem.[here](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager)

is there any other package or a way which works for both? your help will be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: you can show notifications in iOS, but not alarm. unless user clicks on notification, the app won't start

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications ,see may this package can help you

Answer (score 0):

Use the **RestartableTimer** class available in the **dart:async** package.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-async_async/RestartableTimer-class.html

This creates a timer, that will execute asynchronously once. Once the clock starts, then it will run the function passed into its constructor, then it doesn't execute it again. This is not a periodic timer (unless you clear it), and start it again

```
  new RestartableTimer(new Duration(seconds: 1), () async {
   //Navigate to new screen
  });
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but Timer doesn't work once user close the application.